# Hundreds of "undefined reference" errors when linking Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, linker, static-linking, mingw-w64

I am trying to cross-compile a Qt application for Windows using mingw-w64 on Linux. Everything compiles smoothly until the linking stage; I'm getting hundreds of "undefined reference" errors having to do with Qt libraries. Here is a sample: http://pastebin.com/b20Ede7a

Here's my .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = myApp
DEPENDPATH += . res src

QT += core gui
CONFIG += static

isEmpty(TTS_ENGINE) {
    TTS_ENGINE = flite
}

QMAKE_CXX = i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++
QMAKE_LD = i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x -ggdb -DWINDOWS
QMAKE_LIBDIR += /opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt/lib /opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib
QMAKE_LIBS += -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lpng -lz -ljpeg -lwebp -ltiff -lfreetype -lSDL2_ttf -llua `sdl2-config --libs` -lgif -lfontconfig -lm
INCLUDEPATH += . src /opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt/include /opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/include /opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/include/freetype2

# Input
HEADERS +=  bunch/of/headers
FORMS += res/desc.ui
RESOURCES += res/desc.res
SOURCES +=  bunch/of/sources
```

What could be the cause of this problem? I am using static Qt4 from [MXE](http://mxe.cc/).

Edit: Also, here is the output of `i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++ -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/opt/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/mxe/usr/libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-w64-mingw32.static
Configured with: /opt/mxe/tmp-gcc-i686-w64-mingw32.static/gcc-4.9.2/configure --target=i686-w64-mingw32.static --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/opt/mxe/usr --libdir=/opt/mxe/usr/lib --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gcc --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-multilib --without-x --disable-win32-registry --enable-threads=win32 --disable-libgomp --with-cloog=/opt/mxe/usr --with-gmp=/opt/mxe/usr --with-isl=/opt/mxe/usr --with-mpc=/opt/mxe/usr --with-mpfr=/opt/mxe/usr --with-as=/opt/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-as --with-ld=/opt/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld --with-nm=/opt/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-nm
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC)
```

And the failing link command (sorry about the single line):

```
i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++ -Wl,-s -mthreads -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o release/descend.exe object_script.descend.Release  -L'/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt/lib' -L'/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib' -L'/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt/lib' -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lwebp -lfreetype -lSDL2_ttf -llua `sdl2-config --libs` -lgif -lfontconfig -lflite_cmu_us_kal -lflite_cmu_time_awb -lflite_cmu_us_kal16 -lflite_cmu_us_awb -lflite_cmu_us_rms -lflite_cmu_us_slt -lflite_usenglish -lflite_cmu_indic_lang -lflite_cmu_grapheme_lang -lflite_cmulex -lflite_cmu_indic_lex -lflite_cmu_grapheme_lex -lflite -lmingw32 -lqtmain -lQtGui -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -loleaut32 -limm32 -lwinmm -lwinspool -lmsimg32 -lmng -llcms2 -lm -ltiff -llzma -ljpeg -lQtCore -lpng -lole32 -luuid -lws2_32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lz
```

Comment: What does `i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++ -v` tell as version?

Comment: It gives the version as 4.9.2.

Comment: Please show the actual link command in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think your libQtCore.a archive is compiled using a different version of g++. Currently it is trying to use it from the following path at the link step:
   /opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt/lib/libQtCore.a

If you do not mean to use this version, then specify the path to libQtCore.a at the link step (that is compiled using the same version of gcc).

Comment: These Qt libraries were built with the same compiler at the time I installed MXE. I'm thinking about scrapping my Qt build and starting over fresh.

Comment: A good idea would be to also check if libQtCore which contains *.cpp files was compiled with gcc instead of g++